# What are non-periodic heals in world of warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Blizzard has announced that there is a change to one of the mythic plus mechanics, [grievous](https://www.wowhead.com/news=317572/shadowlands-mythic-affix-updates-changes-to-sanguine-grievous-explosive-volcanic).

> Added Functionality: Non-periodic heals now remove 1 application of Grievous Wound.

What heals would count as non-periodic? Direct heals such as chain heal from a shaman, or healing rain that isn't technically a dot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The distinction is in if the healing effect is a 'tick' or directly attributable to the spell. Whenever someone is healed, ask this question:

Does the spell that caused the heal to happen cast in the same frame/game logic tick as the heal itself?

Iff yes, then this is a *direct* heal.

Iff no, and there are multiple instances of time in which heals happen, it is *periodic*. This includes both DoT and channelled effects.

### **Counts as periodic**

- Area effects with 'ticks'. (Healing Rain, shaman).
- DoT spells (Rejuvenation, druid)
- Drain life (Warlock)

### **Not actually periodic**

- Area heals (Healing Circle, priest)
- Direct heals (Chain heal, shaman).
- Combined DoT/Direct spells (Riptide, shaman)<sup>1</sup>.
- Healthstone (Warlock)

1: Only the initial cast will remove a Grievous stack, not every tick.

### **Interesting cases**

For some spells/effects, it's unclear of whether they would count, and likely up to the developer. As it's unlikely every corner case was covered, there may be some surprising inconsistent details. Consider effects like:

- Living seed. (Adds a separate instance of heal not from a spell.)
- Priest' Trail of light (again, separate instance)
- Cloudburst totem
- (etc.)

It's likely up to the specific code implementation of each spell whether or not Grievous would count them as periodic or not. Someone would have to make a giant list of spells and test each one if they count.

It's quite likely most of these would not count as periodic with a few exceptions.

Comment: Is this based on PTR testing or on the behavior of effects with similar language?